# Add several nested JSON properties in a component in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am learning React and have a API request to OpenWeather that results in something like this:

```
{
    coord: {
        lon: -0.13,
        lat: 51.51
    },
    weather: [{
        id: 500,
        main: "Rain",
        description: "light rain",
        icon: "10d"
    }],
    base: "stations",
    main: {
        temp: 293.21,
        pressure: 1011,
        humidity: 86,
        temp_min: 292.45,
        temp_max: 294.26
    },
    wind: {
        speed: 1.54,
        deg: 243,
        gust: 3.08
    },
    rain: {
        3h: 0.78
    },
    clouds: {
        all: 56
    },
    dt: 1466431324,
    sys: {
        type: 3,
        id: 10115,
        message: 0.0463,
        country: "GB",
        sunrise: 1466394185,
        sunset: 1466454093
    },
    id: 2643743,
    name: "London",
    cod: 200
}
```

I'm having problems using several parts of this JSON data.

I can call the result and first layer without problems, but calling any of the nested properties responds in an error saying it can't read the property of undefined.

I guess this is because the state is not defined, does it need to be defined for all the nested layers? I have defined the root, like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var Httprequest = require('../services/weatherservice.js');
var CurrentWeather = require('./CurrentWeather.jsx');

var WeatherApp = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {currentWeather: '', apiCall: ''};
    },

    componentWillMount: function() {
        Httprequest.get('London')
        .then(function(data) {
            this.setState({apiCall: data});
            this.setState({currentWeather: data.weather[0]});
        }.bind(this));
    },

    render: function() {

        var Res = this.state.apiCall;

        return (
                <div>
                <h1>Weather App</h1>
                <CurrentWeather weatherNow={Res.main.humidity} />
                </div>
            );
    }

});

module.exports = Weather;
```

Perhaps I shouldn't use state? I'm thinking of creating a solution where the user can change the city later on that's why I'm using state. **I would appreciate it a lot if someone experienced could explain and perhaps refactor my example using a good practice so that I can learn doing it right.**

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with state per say. It's down to simple checking of whether variables exist before trying to access it's children, if they don't exist, skip or provide alternative behavour

Comment: You should try those todos example to get general understanding of state management.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Kiee so should I check if it exists for every object I want to use?

Comment: @KevinB Sorry for the missunderstanding, the <CurrentWeather is a component from another file which just has a h1 tag with celsiusNow property (testing). If you check closer you can see that its passing the this.props.apiCall to that property, which is data and not data.weather[0].

Comment: Ah, i see. i misread. So what exactly is coming up as undefined? where?

Comment: @KevinB every nested object that I'm trying to render. Would I need to do null check on every? Is there a good way of doing it in React?

Comment: "every" doesn't tell me how you're doing it or where. If you actually have the object, getting to the nested properties would be easy. My guess would be whatever you're using to get to said nested properties isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @KevinB typing celsiusNow={Res.name} gives me "London". Typing Res.wind.speed instead gives me TypeError: Cannot read property 'speed' of undefined instead, same goes for all the other nested objects. I want to use several of them, would I need to define them all first?

Comment: so that means... `Res.wind` is undefined. `console.log(Res)`

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to explain what you have done)

1) before first render you send request which will return data, at state you have `{currentWeather: '', apiCall: ''}`

2) request is async, so 
       `.then(function(data) {
            this.setState({apiCall: data});
            this.setState({currentWeather: data.weather[0]});
        }.bind(this))`
this code will be called after several seconds

3) render method called, in which you doing something like this:

```
this.state.apiCall.main.humidity
```

but, for now in state you still have `{currentWeather: '', apiCall: ''}` so we will have error

how to solve this? simple just add some checks like

> weatherNow={Res && Res.main && Res.main.humidity}

i also recommend you to read react styleguids, for now your component look ugly)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Doing Res && Res.main etc made it work. Could you please explain why it worked? Would I need to do something like that for each property?

Comment: i think you not completely understand async model, look at first render you have only {currentWeather: '', apiCall: ''} this, after promise finished you will got expected state, so best way to show something like spinner or just not render component until it get data from api or just add checks like this weatherNow={Res && Res.main && Res.main.humidity} or have better state at start with all nesteds